# Visual Basic - Calculation in datagridview based on user input

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a airline reservation system, now i have a problem here.

I will ask to user to select the No of passenger and then when user click on "Search" button, the datagridview will filter out the available flight.

Inside the datagridview, a column named "Total Price", will calculate based on the following formula:

(NumericUpDown1)No of passenger * Price Per Person.

Can I have anyone advise how to do this?

[image]

Comment: If the DGV is bound to a datatable, you could put the passenger in the datatable (ir need not be visible) and then define `TotalPrice` column as an [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: hi Plutonix, thanks for your advise, may i know how to define it? I mean where can set this define? i am a beginner , thank you

Comment: You may.  [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)